# Derive $y=x\cos^3(5x+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I derive the function $y=x\cos^3(5x+1)$ ?
I obtain this derivative
$$y=\cos^3(5x+1)+\left(3\cos^2(5x+1)\cdot2\cos(5x+1)\cdot\sin(5x+1)\cdot5\right)x$$
Is it wrong? My book gave me another solution probably because it semplifies its form.. But I'm not sure if what I did is correct can you help me? 
Thanks in advance, I'm preparing for a test and I'm quiete worried...

Comment: There are a couple of errors in the differentiation of $\cos^3(5x+1)$. It should be $(5)(-\sin(5x+1))(3\cos^2(5x+1))$.

Comment: In the future, it may help to show your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know just whether you are correct or wrong, you are wrong.

The answer in your way will be
$$\cos^3(5x+1)+\left(3\cos^2(5x+1)(-\sin(5x+1))\times 5\right)x.$$

If you feel difficulty to understand this, then let $f(x)=\cos(5x+1)$ and $g(x)=\left(f(x)\right)^3$.

$g^\prime(x)=3\times\left(f(x)\right)^2\times f^\prime (x).$

Comment: Why you don't derive cos^2(5x+1) ? This is what I don't understand

Comment: Because you have just derived cos^3(5x+1) then you have to derive only cos(5x+1) right?

Comment: yes. then we need to get $f^\prime(x)$, right? then again let $h(x)=5x+1$, so $(\cos h(x))^\prime=-\sin h(x)\times h^\prime(x)$. so, now we get what I wrote.

Comment: now I've understand my mistake, thank you!

Comment: OK, My big pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

Using the **Product Rule** which is:

$$y = f(x)g(x), \space \implies y' = f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x)$$

Now let $f(x) =x$ and $g(x) = \cos^3(5x+1)=(\cos(5x+1))^3$

$$y' =x \cdot 3\cos^2(5x+1) \cdot -\sin (5x+1) \cdot 5 +\cos^3(5x+1) \cdot 1$$
$$=\cos^3(5x+1) - 15x\cos^2(5x+1)\sin(5x+1)$$

Using the **Chain Rule** to calculate $(\cos(5x+1))^3$

Let $\cos(5x+1)=u, \implies h(x) =u^3$
The chain rule says, that $y' = h'(x)\cdot u'$, and therefore, $$(\cos(5x+1))^3)' = 3u^2 \cdot -\sin(5x+1)\cdot 5 = -15u^2\sin(5x+1)$$

But $u=\cos(5x+1)$, so therefore, 
$$-15u^2\sin(5x+1) = -15(\cos(5x+1))^2\sin(5x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: It's better to use $$\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A\implies\cos^3A=\frac{\cos3A+3\cos A}4$$

Otherwise using [Product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), $$\frac{d\left(x\cdot\cos^3(5x+1)\right)}{dx}=x\cdot\frac{d\left(\cos^3(5x+1)\right)}{dx}+\cos^3(5x+1)\frac{dx}{dx}$$

Now using [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), $$\frac{d\left(\cos^3(5x+1)\right)}{dx}=\frac{d\left(\cos^3(5x+1)\right)}{d( \cos(5x+1))}\cdot\frac{d(\cos(5x+1))}{d(5x+1)}\cdot\frac{d(5x+1)}{dx}$$

Comment: Sorry but I just started to study derivatives so I don't know how to use Chain Rule

Comment: @Dipok, you have implicitly done that. Btw, the link should help

Comment: Sounds like you should do a web/video search of "chain rule", Dipok!

Comment: If I've implicitly done that probably I will figure it out later, but now I'm not supposed to use chain rule but I will lern how to use it

Comment: @Dipok, it's your choice when to learn these elementary formulae of  differentiation

Comment: I'm just attending a math course in my grammar school, I'm a student so I'm following my professor ;-)